# Combine Locations and output Combined Data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

The idea is to take all the "Locations" and merge them together to give out a number for my chart to read. So lets say you have 5 "Locations" that are New York with varying "Dates". I want to merge all 5 together and output a number of 5, as well as the merged "Punches" from the .json.  Right now I have it grab Locations, and Merge similar Punches. But I want to get total number of instances of New York for example and output that number as well.

**chart.json**

```
    [  
   {  
      "Date":"2003",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2003",
      "Punches":"1",
      "Locations":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2004",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"Chicago"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2004",
      "Punches":"1",
      "Locations":"Chicago"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2004",
      "Punches":"1",
      "Locations":"Ohio"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2004",
      "Punches":"1",
      "Locations":"Ohio"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2007",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"Ohio"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2007",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"Florida"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2009",
      "Punches":"1",
      "Locations":"Florida"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2007",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2009",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2009",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"Chicago"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2010",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2010",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"Florida"
   }
]
```

**JS**

```
function LocationMerge()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'data.json',
                data:{},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var string = JSON.stringify(data);
                    var objects = $.parseJSON(string);
                    var categories = new Array();
                    var mergedPieces = new Array();
                    var i = 0;
                    _.each(objects, function(obj)
                    {
                        var existingObj;
                        if ($.inArray(obj.Locations, categories) >= 0)
                        {
                            existingObj = _.find(objects, function(o)
                            {
                                return o.Locations=== obj.Locations;
                            });
                            existingObj["Punches"] += obj["Punches"];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mergedPieces[i] = obj;
                            categories[i] = obj.Locations;
                            i++;
                        }
                    });
                    mergedPieces = _.sortBy(mergedPieces, function(obj)
                    {
                        return obj["Punches"];
                    }).reverse();
                    _.each(mergedPieces, function(obj)
                    {
                        var output = '';
                        _.each(obj, function(val, key)
                        {
                            output += key + ': ' + val + '<br>';
                        });
                        output += '<br>';
                        console.log(output);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your success function. check out the demo (console output) for the result

```
var data = [{"Date": "2003", "Punches": "0", "Locations": "New York"}, {"Date": "2003", "Punches": "1", "Locations": "New York"}, {"Date": "2004", "Punches": "0", "Locations": "Chicago"}, {"Date": "2004", "Punches": "1", "Locations": "Chicago"}, {"Date": "2004", "Punches": "1", "Locations": "Ohio"}, {"Date": "2004", "Punches": "1", "Locations": "Ohio"}, {"Date": "2007", "Punches": "0", "Locations": "Ohio"}, {"Date": "2007", "Punches": "0", "Locations": "Florida"}, {"Date": "2009", "Punches": "1", "Locations": "Florida"}, {"Date": "2007", "Punches": "0", "Locations": "New York"}, {"Date": "2009", "Punches": "0", "Locations": "New York"}, {"Date": "2009", "Punches": "0", "Locations": "Chicago"}, {"Date": "2010", "Punches": "0", "Locations": "New York"}, {"Date": "2010", "Punches": "0", "Locations": "Florida"}];

function LocationMerge()
{
    var newObj = new Object();
    _.each(data, function(obj){
       if(newObj[obj.Locations] === undefined)
           newObj[obj.Locations] = {"Location":obj.Locations,"Punches":parseInt(obj.Punches),"items":1};
       else{
           newObj[obj.Locations]["Punches"]+=parseInt(obj.Punches);
           newObj[obj.Locations]["items"]++;
       }
    });
    console.log(newObj);
}

LocationMerge();
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/a40d1c3n/)**

Comment: @askmeaquestion1234: please close the solution if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

```
Code below
```

```js
var dataset = [  
   {  
      "Date":"2003",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2003",
      "Punches":"1",
      "Locations":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2004",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"Chicago"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2004",
      "Punches":"1",
      "Locations":"Chicago"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2004",
      "Punches":"1",
      "Locations":"Ohio"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2004",
      "Punches":"1",
      "Locations":"Ohio"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2007",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"Ohio"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2007",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"Florida"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2009",
      "Punches":"1",
      "Locations":"Florida"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2007",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2009",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2009",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"Chicago"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2010",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "Date":"2010",
      "Punches":"0",
      "Locations":"Florida"
   }
];

map = {};
dataset.forEach(function(data){ if(map[data.Locations]){map[data.Locations]=map[data.Locations]+1}else{map[data.Locations]=1}});

snippet.log(map)
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: 1 up for a single line solution :)